# NSMutableURLRequest - HTTPBody from Swift Array

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlrequest

I need to send a post request to my server with HTTPBody of Array. Here's my array of parameters:

```
params = [
            "message"  : [
                "alert" : "Find your iPhone",
                "sound" : "Binocular_Default.caf"
            ]
        ]
```

Now I need to set `NSMutableURLRequest`'s `HTTPBody` to this array. How can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create mutable request with your params. and try with following code

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "yoururl"))
var session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

//create dictionary with your parameters
var params = ["username":"test", "password":"pass"] as Dictionary<String, String>

var err: NSError?
request.HTTPBody = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(params, options: nil, error: &err)
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

var task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    println("Response: \(response)")
    var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("Body: \(strData)")
    var err: NSError?
    var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error: &err) as? NSDictionary

    // Did the JSONObjectWithData constructor return an error? If so, log the error to the console
    if(err != nil) {
        println(err!.localizedDescription)
    }
    else {

    }
})

task.resume()
```